# Set Language for JText::_()

Tags: php, joomla, translation, joomla3.4

Setting:
7 System Lanaguages
An editor page which is entirely German (no language switcher).
However part of the page is a preview screen where the editor ought to see the edited content already translated into the respective System Language.

Is there a way I can give `JText::_('TRANSLATE_STRING')` a parameter which determines the target language of the translation?

Is there another function which gives easy access to the translation?

Or can I change the current language of the Session programatically?

I am a little lost on the documentations I find online and stuck without the right ideas or terms to research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JFactory::getLanguage()` will get you the current language object (JLanguage instance).

`JLanguage::getInstance($lang)` can get you the language instance you want.  You'll need to specify the language code as parameter.  You can then use the instance to translate language resources.

For example:

```
$lang = JLanguage::getInstance('de-DE');
echo $lang->_('TRANSLATE_STRING');
```

Would output the german version of 'TRANSLATE_STRING'